# Change ng-src value onclick

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've an AngularJS page and I want it to change ng-src value of an element when clicking on another element. I intialized variable src:

```
data-ng-init="src='assets/img/projects/1'
```

Then I made this element:

```
<img data-ng-src="{{src}}/1.jpg" id="img1">
```

And finally I want when someone clicks on my link, It change that src to `{{src}}/1a.jpg`, So I tried this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="selectImage('lists/1.html');document.getElementById('img1').setAttribute('data-ng-src', '{{src}}/1a.jpg');"></a>
```

(Don't care about my empty link, I know how to click on it...), My problem is, The value of src doesn't change and My page is still the first image, How can I improve my code to change value `{{src}}/1.jpg` to `{{src}}/1a.jpg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new varibale **image**

```
data-ng-init="src='assets/img/projects/1'; image='1.jpg'"
```

Then HTML Element

```
<img data-ng-src="{{src}}/{{image}}" id="img1">
```

If someone clicks on you link the change the **image** value

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="selectImage('lists/1.html'); image='1a.jpg'"></a>
```

Hope this helps ! Thanks.

Comment: Yup ! Thanks buddy

Answer (score 4):

Very very wrong code, You combine standard DOM modification with angular. Choose only one solution not combine in this way. Check my example code:

```js
var app=angular.module("image",[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="image" ng-init="src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/161dac2e231b0f6b4340000328e18bcf?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'">
<img data-ng-src="{{src}}" id="img1">


<button ng-click="src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a5af44879d481c3c15a4b2dd55007322?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG'" >Change image src to different</button>
</div>
```

So only set `src` scope variable to different src and it works like a charm.

```
ng-click="src='different src'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set ng-click to function in your controller, that changes "src" variable in your scope.

Comment: src variable's not a scope - I initialized it using ng-init - Doesn't it a matter?

Comment: even if you initialize it with init it still is in scope. Nevertheless it will be better practice to initialize your variables in controllers. ng-init="src='assets/img/projects/1'" is equal to $scope.src='assets/img/projects/1' in your controller